# How to set relationships and fetch data

Tags: swift, core-data, ios8, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to make a grocery list app. I have 2 entities in my data model: List and Item

I want to make multiple Lists that can have many items.

I've created the relationship (and inverse) List contains Item. But when I create and Item I don't know how to set newItem_A into List_A and subsequently fetch all items contained_in List_A

Comment: You should add code that shows what you've done, what you're trying to do, an any errors you're running into. It's hard to give any advice from what you've written so far.

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/iMac239/CoreDataRelationshipDemo

Comment: Have you auto-generated the entity classes? What methods do they offer?

Comment: That github repo is amazing, thanks so much. I was able to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bluehound's comment, I was able to figure it out! Quite a simple solution, boils down to my ignorance and Xcode having a lot of windows.

In order to get the one to many relationship I needed, I had to change the relationship type to "to many" on the List entity. It's an option in the Data Model Inspector on the right side.

By doing this, it gave the List class an items variable of NSSet instead of the NSManagedObject it was making before.

My List Class:

```
@objc(List)
class List: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var items: NSSet

}
```

My Item class:

```
@objc(Item)
class Item: NSManagedObject {

  @NSManaged var category: String
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var pricePerUnit: NSDecimalNumber
  @NSManaged var quantity: NSNumber
  @NSManaged var unit: String
  @NSManaged var list: List
}
```